# Al-Fihrist survivals

Tags: ancient-greece, islamic-science

I wonder if there is any estimate about the percentage of the books that survived from Islamic ancient time listed in Ibn Nadim's Al Fihrist?
Is there any counterpart of this work belonging to ancient Greece? If yes, what percentage of Greek books has survived?

Comment: Is this about science? Isn't the catalogue about poetry and teology?

Comment: I think it contains various subjects including poetry and theology but not limited to them. For example, chapter seven is about science.